# Why the GetAction function in the useEffect is avoid if i am inserting the data? ( i am using mern with react native stack)

Tags: react-native, get, save, crud, mern

in the code i  insert two array , action, time,  then i save it in my db model  , but  in the useEffect that  contains the saved data ,  shows an emty array  or just nothing

i  already checked that  the api connection is right,

before the useeffect had an setInterval but i made it more simple to try of find the error

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { guardarAcciones, eliminarAccionesA, obtenerAcciones } from './api';

const ASA = () =\> {
const \[acciones, setAcciones\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[tiempos, setTiempos\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[guardada, setGuardada\] = useState(false);
// Establecer un valor predeterminado de 2 elementos
const numElementos = 2;

// Definir un estado para las acciones obtenidas del API
const \[accionesObtenidas, setAccionesObtenidas\] = useState(\[\]);
// Actualizar las acciones obtenidas del API cada 5 segundos
useEffect(() =\> {
obtenerAcciones()
.then((res) =\> {
console.log('Acciones obtenidas', res.data);
setAccionesObtenidas(res.data);
} )

}, \[\]);

    // Renderizar la lista de acciones y tiempos obtenidos del API
    const listaAccionesObtenidas = accionesObtenidas.length > 0 ? accionesObtenidas.map((accion, index) => {
     console.log('Lista de acciones obtenidas', accion);
      return (
        <View key={index}>
          <Text>{accion.accion}</Text>
          <Text>{accion.tiempo}</Text>
          <Button title="Eliminar" onPress={() => handleEliminarAccion(index)} />
        </View>
      );
    }) : null;

const inputs = \[\];
for (let i = 0; i \< numElementos; i++) {
inputs.push(
\<View key={i}\>
\<Text\>Acción {i + 1}:\</Text\>
\<TextInput
placeholder="Insertar acción"
value={acciones\[i\] || ''}
onChangeText={(text) =\> handleCambiarAccion(i, text)}
/\>
\<Text\>Tiempo {i + 1}:\</Text\>
\<TextInput
placeholder="Insertar tiempo"
value={tiempos\[i\] || ''}
onChangeText={(text) =\> handleCambiarTiempo(i, text)}
/\>
\</View\>
);
}

const handleEliminarAccion = (index) =\> {
const accionAEliminar = accionesObtenidas\[index\];
eliminarAccionesA(accionAEliminar).then(() =\> {
const nuevasAcciones = accionesObtenidas.filter((accion, i) =\> i !== index);
setAccionesObtenidas(nuevasAcciones);
}).catch((error) =\> {
console.log(error);
});
};

const handleGuardarAccion = () =\> {
let todasLasAccionesDefinidas = true;
for (let i = 0; i \< acciones.length; i++) {
if (!acciones\[i\] || !tiempos\[i\]) {
todasLasAccionesDefinidas = false;
break;
}
}
if (todasLasAccionesDefinidas) {
try {
const accionesYTiempos = acciones.map((accion, index) =\> {
return { accion: accion, tiempo: tiempos\[index\] };
});
guardarAcciones(accionesYTiempos);
setGuardada(true);
console.log('Guardado correctamente', accionesYTiempos);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
setGuardada(false);
}
} else {
console.log('Debe definir todas las acciones y tiempos');
setGuardada(false);
}
};

const handleCambiarAccion = (index, value) =\> {
const nuevasAcciones = \[...acciones\];
nuevasAcciones\[index\] = value;
setAcciones(nuevasAcciones);
};

const handleCambiarTiempo = (index, value) =\> {
const nuevosTiempos = \[...tiempos\];
nuevosTiempos\[index\] = value;
setTiempos(nuevosTiempos);
};

return (
\<View\>
{inputs}
\<Button title="Guardar" placeholder="guardar" onPress={handleGuardarAccion} /\>
{guardada && \<Text\>Guardado correctamente\</Text\>}
{listaAccionesObtenidas}
\</View\>
);
};

export default ASA;\
```

```
// Importar el modelo de datos

const { AccionA} = require( '../models/adaptationA');

const newAccionesA = async (req, res) =\> {
try {
const nuevasAcciones = req.body.acciones;
const tiempo = req.body.tiempo;

    const accion = new AccionA({
      acciones: nuevasAcciones,
      tiempo: tiempo
    });
    
    const accionGuardada = await accion.save();
    
    console.log('Acciones guardadas en la base de datos');
    res.status(200).json(accionGuardada);

} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
res.status(500).send('Error al guardar las acciones en la base de datos');
}
};

const getAccionesA = async (req, res) =\> {
try {
const acciones = await AccionA.find({})

    if (Array.isArray(acciones) && acciones.length > 0)
    res.status(200).json(acciones);

console.log("acciones obtenidas de la base de datos",acciones)
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
res.status(500).send('Error al obtener las acciones de la base de datos');
}
};

const eliminarAccionesA = async (req, res) =\> {
try {
await AccionA.deleteMany();
console.log('Acciones eliminadas de la base de datos');
res.status(200).send('Acciones eliminadas de la base de datos');
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
res.status(500).send('Error al eliminar las acciones de la base de datos');
}
};

module.exports = {eliminarAccionesA,newAccionesA , getAccionesA}\`

\`the model data   const mongoose= require("mongoose")
```

```
const accionASchema = new mongoose.Schema({
acciones: \[String\],
tiempo: \[Number\]
});

const AccionA= mongoose.model('AccionA', accionASchema);

module.exports = {AccionA}
```

i tried making the useffect statement more simple, using console logs to see the expected data, review the code over and over but at the end the getAction give me nothing  , but the function that save the data works and it shows me in the browser the inserted data.

i expect that when i saved the data array , with  the useffect show the data array  with tha api function getAction .

Actually the getAcciones server function  doesnt get the saved data